# How to assign subcategory products to their respective parent category in magento go

Tags: php, magento, magento-go

I am working on magento go.I have many categories and its sub categories.

All the sub category has so many products where as parent category don't have any product assigned to it.

`My question is how can i assign all the sub category products to their respective parent category.`

Please help me as it will take a lot of time to do it manually.

Comment: Did you try by enabling 'is Anchor->Yes' in the Display settings at Manage Categories of the Parent Category? Because I just tried it and it solves your issue. Let

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that you followed this method or not, But check with this. In the below image, the product is assigned to a category of cellphones which is parent category of Electronics. If you want to assign the same product for Parent category ie., for Electronics also, Go to `Manage Products` and select particular product and Go to `Categories` section and select Parent category also. In this below image, if I would like to assign it to parent category then I have to select Electronics also. Let me know if you have any doubts in this.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for reply.I have 2000 products and more than 80 category.So I can't go to do it manually.I want to do it in bulk,like any php code or database code which works on magento go platform

Comment: As I could not find any answer i did it by editing the exported csv file.Still any help if any one did it by code.